# Pandas Apply using input from first row and not from each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following table and want to use the RoadSegmentOrigin as input for a new column OriginCoordinates

```
RoadSegmentOrigin,RoadSegmentDest,trip_id,planned_duration
AREI2,JD4,107_1_D_1,32
JD4,PNG4,107_1_D_1,55
PNG4,TVA2,107_1_D_1,55
```

This is what I'm using:

```
df_RoadSegments["OriginCoordinates"] = df_RoadSegments.apply(lambda x: GetStopsCoordinates(df_Stops, x["RoadSegmentOrigin"]), axis=1)
```

But what I'm getting as result is like the GetStopsCoordinates is using only the first RoadSegmentOrigin as input and does not update every row

```
     RoadSegmentOrigin  ...                   OriginCoordinates
0                  AREI2  ...  41.1591084955401,-8.55577748652738
1                    JD4  ...  41.1591084955401,-8.55577748652738
2                   PNG4  ...  41.1591084955401,-8.55577748652738
```

Comment: and what is `GetStopsCoordinates`?

Comment: We need to know what is in `df_Stops` and `GetStopsCoordinates` to figure out this issue...

Comment: df_Stops is a dataframe of a file that contains the coordinates of each RoadSegmentOrigin. GetStopsCoordinates is a function that returns the coordinates.

Comment: any ideas @Nick ?

Comment: The issue must be somewhere in those two, as a simple `df_RoadSegments.apply(lambda x:x["RoadSegmentOrigin"], axis=1)` clearly shows that the correct value is being passed to the function